# Sparkling Theme doesn't compatible with PHP-8

Tags: php, wordpress, php-8

After upgrading to PHP 8.0 the site does not work -shows a white page- and causes this error:

```
Got error 'PHP message: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "HEADER" in
C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\wp-content\themes\sparkling\inc\custom-header.php:56
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(292): sparkling_header_style('')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(316): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\wp-includes\plugin.php(484): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\wp-includes\general-template.php(3009): do_action('wp_head')
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\wp-content\themes\sparkling\header.php(30): wp_head()
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\wp-includes\template.php(730): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\wp-includes\template.php(676): load_template('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', true, Array)
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\wp-includes\general-template.php(48): locate_template(Array, true, true, Array)
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\wp-content\themes\sparkling\index.php(11): get_header()
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\wp-includes\template-loader.php(106): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\index.php(17): require('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#12 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\wp-content\themes\sparkling\inc\custom-header.php on line 56
```

Comment: A quick search for your error msg shows: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/php-8-not-compatible/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the code at wp-content/themes/sparkling/inc/custom-header.php, this must be changed:

```
@$a = HEADER; // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine
@$b = TEXTCOLOR; // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine
```

To

```
@$a = 'HEADER'; // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine
@$b = 'TEXTCOLOR'; // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine
```